# How to prevent instance variables of a parent are overwritten by child class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two pretty simple classes written below. `Human` inherits from the `Mammal` class. When I call `print(jo.drinkMe("sage"))`, I expect "sick" to be printed, but "fine" is printed. I think that `self.problem` in the `Human` class overwrites `self.problem` in the `Mammal` class. What do I need to do to my code in order for the print statement at the end to print "sick"?

```
class Mammal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.problem = "sage"
        self.result = "sick"

    def drinkMe(self,tea):
        if tea == self.problem:
            return self.result
        else:
            return "fine"

class Human(Mammal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.problem = "paint"
        self.result = "die"
    def drinkMe(self,tea):
        if tea == self.problem:
            return self.result
        else:
            return super().drinkMe(tea)

jo = Human()
to = Mammal()
print(jo.drinkMe("sage"))
```

Comment: Do you want these `problem` variables to be separate? What should happen if you try to do `jo.problem`? If the answer to the first question is "yes" and the answer to the second is "doesn't matter" or "you shouldn't do that", then this might be one of the times it's actually a good idea to use leading double underscores.

Comment: Neither the `Human` nor `Mammal` classes have an attribute `problem`, so it cannot be overwritten.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Dropping this to a newcomer without explanation might not be a good idea though.

Comment: @user2357112 The answer to the first is "yes" and the answer to the second is "doesn't matter". I just want to know why "fine" is returned instead of "sick".

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that `Mammal` only sets its instance attributes `problem` and `result` when it's instantiated. `jo = Human()` instantiates a `Mammal` object, but then clobbers the `problem` and `result` attributes into its own. To be verbose, you have:

```
class Human(Mammal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # calls `Mammal.__init__()`, which sets
        # self.problem = "sage"
        # self.result = "sick"
        self.problem = "paint"
        self.result = "die"
        # overwrites what `Mammal.__init__()` did a
        # couple lines ago.
   ...
```

You might instead do:

```
class Mammal(object):
    problem = "sage"
    result = "sick"

    def drink_me(self, tea):
        if tea == self.problem:
            return self.result
        else:
            return "fine"


class Human(Mammal):
    problem = "paint"
    result = die

    def drink_me(self, tea):
        if tea == self.problem:
            return self.result
        else:
            return super().drink_me(tea)
```

Comment: "jo = Human() never instantiates a Mammal object" - what do you mean? It instantiates the Mammal object `jo`. It's not like they forgot to call `super().__init__` and they're skipping the superclass's initialization; they've just stomped over the values the superclass's `__init__` set.

Comment: @user2357112 true, I phrased that poorly. I'll delete and re-write.

Comment: @user2357112 is that better?

Comment: Well, it's not outright wrong any more, but it's still kind of confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps. It is a little different way of thinking than your original code, but honestly the code you posted was going to require some messy `super()` calls. I think that what you're aiming for is a subclass of `Mammal()` with additional options for a result from `drinkMe()`

What about taking this approach: All `Mammals` now have a dictionary with drinks and results. Subclasses update this dictionary with their own custom responses to the drink. This way you have a single function that just returns the response for a drink. What should happen if an instance drinks something that does not have a response set? Now you only need to add exception handling once inside `drinkMe()`.

```
class Mammal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.problems = {'sage': 'sick'}

    def drinkMe(self, tea):
        return self.problems[tea]


class Human(Mammal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.problems.update({'paint': 'die'})

jo = Human()
print(jo.drinkMe("sage"))
```

Edit: To comment more on why your original code printed `fine` instead of `sick`.

When you instatiated a `Human` called `jo`, `jo.problem` is set to `paint`. So, `jo.drinkMe` calls `super.drinkMe` which again checks if `tea == self.problem`. But remember, you *still have not changed `jo.problem`*. It is still set to `paint`, and so `fine` gets returned.

`self` is the instance itself, in this case it is `jo` and when you call the `super.drinkMe()`, `super.__init__()` is not run again, so `self.problem` is still set to whatever it was.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple way to prevent the instance variables declared in `Human` from overriding those in `Mammal`. The code basically just reassigns the values of `self.problem` and `self.result` each time `drink_me` is called:

```
class Mammal:

    def __init__(self):
        self.problem = "sage"
        self.result = "sick"

    def drinkMe(self,tea):
        if tea == self.problem:
            return self.result
        else:
            return "fine"
class Human(Mammal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.problem = "paint"
        self.result = "die"
    def drinkMe(self,tea):
        result = ''
        if tea == self.problem:
            return self.result
        else:
            super().__init__()
            result = super().drinkMe(tea)
            self.__init__()
            return(result)
jo = Human()
print(jo.drinkMe("sage"))
print(jo.drinkMe("paint"))
```

This code first prints 'sick' and then 'die'.